# Monitor Airflow Dataset dependencies

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm having trouble with this feature. For example, if a DAG C depends on datasets A and B, and DAG A is disabled, DAG C does not run. Additionally, if dataset B is run manually for remediation, this may disrupt the dependencies of DAG C. Is there a way to monitor and alert on these situations, or a strategy to prevent them? Also, I'm wondering how to reset the state of a dataset, for example, after a rerun of a date in dataset A, to avoid disturbing the dependencies of DAG C.

One idea I have is to monitor DAGs using the Airflow database. For example, if a DAG usually runs every 24 hours but its last run was older, I would trigger an alert.